# Replace value in one collection with corresponding value in other collection MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

I have two collections:

```
Collection A
----------------
...
"sometag"  "1"
...


Collection B
----------------
"1" "one"
"2" "two"
```

I want to replace all the sometag values in all documents in collection A with the corresponding value in B.

So, sometag "1" should be changed into sometag "one", and sometag "2" into sometag "two"

Can this be done in a single query? So, without iterating over all occurences in B?

I can't seem to figure this out. However, iterating over B and then doing a query works.

```
/*
 * tarTag: the target tag in A (e.g. "sometag")
 * current: an iterator over coll B
 * keyTag: the key in B (e.g. "1")
 * valTag: the corresponding value in B (e.g. "one")
 */
BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject(tarTag,        current.get(keyTag));
BasicDBObject update = new BasicDBObject("$set", 
                                        new BasicDBObject(tarTag, current.get(valTag)));
collectionA.updateMany(searchQuery, update);
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Of course this can't be done in a single query. You can't read document A and modify document B in the same query.

You can't even do this in a single document, i.e. `update key 'a' with contents of key 'b'` doesn't work.

I would read all documents from Collection B, and then update Collection A with that data. You may need to update document by document.

Comment: Was afraid so. Then to speed things up, it should help creating an index on tarTag in CollectionA right? Only... I hardly notice any difference.

Comment: How many documents are in there? I don't think that you'll notice any difference for 500 documents in collection A if there's no index. you could execute your query with `explain()` to see if the index gets used.

Comment: Collection B is less than 100 items, for now Collection A is also less than 100 but will eventually reach appr. 100000. Actually, it makes sense what you say. Silly I didn't think of it.